# Using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf outside of HTTP/web/controllers

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot utility application that is *not* a web service. It exposes no RESTful/GQL (HTTP) endpoints. It consumes off a queue and does work. But I like to still make it a Spring Boot app anyways because there are so many non-web related features (dependency injection, JPA, caching, etc.).

One new thing that this utility app now needs to do is read Thymeleaf-formatted HTML templates from the file system, inject it and bind variables to it, and upload the fully templated version to S3. Hence if it reads the following `vendor-abc.html` from the file system:

```
<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">    
    <table>    
        <tr>    
            <td><h4>User Name: </h4></td>    
            <td><h4 th:text="${user.name}"></h4></td>    
        </tr>    
        <tr>    
            <td><h4>Email ID: </h4></td>    
            <td><h4 th:text="${user.email}"></h4></td>    
        </tr>    
    </table>    
</html>
```

And its bindings are as follows:

```
@Data // lombok to generate ctors/getters/setters/etc.
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}

User user = new User("Jerry Jingleheimer", "jj@example.com");
```

Then the following `vendor-abc-output.html` file will be uploaded to AWS S3:

```
<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">    
    <table>    
        <tr>    
            <td><h4>User Name: </h4></td>    
            <td><h4>Jerry Jingleheimer</h4></td>    
        </tr>    
        <tr>    
            <td><h4>Email ID: </h4></td>    
            <td><h4>jj@example.com</h4></td>    
        </tr>    
    </table>    
</html>
```

All Thymeleaf examples that I can find involve `@Controller`-annotated classes whose methods get injected with `@Model` like so:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String mainWithParam(
        @RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "") 
        String name, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", name);

    return "welcome"; //view

}
```

But here, I will have a single `@Service`-annotated class that has to do all this work (no `@Model`):

```
@Service
public class S3FileTemplater {
    
    public void templatizeAndUpload(File htmlTemplate, User user) {

        // fetch all the Thymelead-templated code out of the file
        String htmlContent = Files.readString(Paths.get(htmlTemplate));

        // how to inject 'user' into 'htmlContent' via Thymeleaf?
        String finalContentWithUser = ???

        // upload to S3
        s3Client.upload(finalContentWithUser);

    }
}
```

**What do I have to do so that the file gets templated by Thymeleaf properly?**

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73739292/how-to-use-thymeleaf-to-generate-static-files/73749027#73749027 -- you can use `context.setVariable("variableName", variable);` to set variables and run Thymeleaf without a server/controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SpringTemplateEngine](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.9.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring5/SpringTemplateEngine.html) class to process your templates, set appropriate Context and send it to your AWS S3.

Here some code example:

```
@Autowired 
private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

public String prepareTemplates(String username, String email) {
         Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
         params.put("username", username);
         params.put("email", email);
         Context context = new Context();
         context.setVariables(params);
         return templateEngine.process("template.html", context);
     }
```

Here reference [link](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc) for further details.

Comment: Thank you @Aleson(+1), does Thymeleaf expect `template.html` to exist anywhere specifically (such as `src/main/resources/thymeleaf`, etc.)? Is there a way to override where Thymeleaf is looking for template files?

Comment: Spring boot expect or defaults the location of the thymeleaf templates to be in `classpath:/templates/` here is the reference link https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.templating.spring.thymeleaf.prefix, yes you can override this either by application properties or by bean configuration shown here https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc