Is it possible to automatically generate and persist a static html file out of Thymeleaf template in maven?
I have a Spring Boot app with a Thymeleaf template (i.e. resources\templates\index.html), which is served as the app home page.
Some while ago, I decided to host the home page outside of the app i.e. on AWS S3, so I've been trying to find a way to automatically generate an html file out of the Thymeleaf template and persist it, so I could deploy it there. Eventually, what I ended up doing is just hitting the home page and manually copy/pasting the page source into a file. 
Obviously it's not ideal, so still wondering if there's a way to build such a file as part of the maven build?

You can configure Thymeleaf to run without a web server... I would create a java application and have it generate the files locally. (You can probably do this in maven, but I don't know how/why you would over just creating a java program that does the same thing.) Something like this for example should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73739292/how-to-generate-static-files-from-a-spring-thymeleaf-project/73749027#73749027 -- except instead of doing a System.out at the end you write it to a file.

Thank you for your suggestion.
To you answer your question: "I don't know how/why you would over just creating a java program that does the same thing":

building artifacts belongs to a build tool (unless there's no other way);
your workaround is tied to Spring, so it won't work in JEE or in a standalone java app. As you may notice, even though I am using SpringBoot, I didn't tag my questions with #spring-boot because I was looking for a generic solution.


I frequently run this sort of solution to test Thymeleaf running as standalone Java... it does use parts of spring, but doesn't start a server or use Spring Boot or JEE.
